# How to group result by query in orm

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework

Can i group results on the basic of field in User model.

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USERTYPE = (('1','type_1'),('2','type_2'),....)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=USERTYPE)
    .....
```

**views.py**

```
User.object.all().values('first_name','last_name')
```

How can i get all users data with groupby there type in below format by using django ORM query only..

```
{  
   "type_1":[  
      {  
         "first_name":"abc",
         "last_name":"xzy"
      },
      {  
         "first_name":"abcd",
         "last_name":"wxzy"
      }
   ],
   "type_2":[  
      {  
         "first_name":"abcdd",
         "last_name":"xzddy"
      },
      {  
         "first_name":"absdcd",
         "last_name":"wxsdzy"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that in a query itself. But you can do some post-processing on the query:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import methodcaller

qs = User.object.order_by('user_type')

result = {
    k: [{ 'first_name': u.first_name, 'last_name': u.last_name } for u in us]
    for k, us in groupby(qs, methodcaller('get_user_type_display'))
}
```

We here thus order the queryset by the `user_type` field, and then let `groupby(..)` make groups based on the `get_user_type_display()` method. Then we can make sublists for each such group.